# .Net Core Telegram.Bot failed with error "SSL Connection could not be established"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, telegram, telegram-bot

I try to use [this](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot) telegram bot library. My code is simple:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using Telegram.Bot;
namespace telegram
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string token = "mytoken";
        private static string msg = "Test";
        private static int chatId = 11111111;    
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bot = new TelegramBotClient(token);
            await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, msg); 
        }
    }
}
```

But after compilation, I get this error message:

[image: #]

Inner exception 1:

[image]

Inner exception 2: 
Win32Exception: An unexpected message was received or it is in the wrong format.

I believe there is an elementary error and its solution, but, unfortunately, I do not know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs "Bots can't initiate conversations with users."

You need to wait for a user to call your bot `bot.OnMessage += BotOnMessageReceived` and then you can respond. You can't create ChatIDs, the system does that.

Comment: Chat id - This is the chat ID in which the bot has already been added and assigned by the administrator. If I open in browser, this link - message will be sent to this chat https :// api.telegram.org/bot<bot_key>/sendMessage?chat_id=-100124567153&text=test